# What's the cleanest way to pass a typename into a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

I'm interested in writing a lambda function that will, among other things, call `std::make_unique`.  To call `std::make_unique` I need a typename, but it would seem that in order to directly pass the typename into the lambda function, I would have to make the lambda variable a template:

```
struct SpecialThing
{
    SpecialThing(/* some arguments */) {}
}

void f()
{
    template <typename Thing>
    auto createThing = [](auto&&... parameters)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Thing>(std::forward<decltype(parameters)>(parameters)...);
    };

    auto thing = createThing<SpecialThing>(/* some construction parameters */);
}
```

But my compiler (GCC 4.9.2) doesn't seem to like this.  (I didn't really expect it to, though I know little enough about template variables that I couldn't be sure it wouldn't.)

Suppose I'm really determined to keep `createThing` a local variable of lambda-function type.  How cleanly can I manage to wrap `std::make_unique` in this fashion?  Here's the best I've got so far:

```
void f()
{
    auto createThing = [](auto dummyThingPointer, auto&&... parameters)
    {
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(dummyThingPointer)>::type Thing;
        return std::make_unique<Thing>(std::forward<decltype(parameters)>(parameters)...);
    };

    auto thing = createThing(static_cast<SpecialThing*>(nullptr), /* some construction parameters */);
}
```

It's wordy, but it isn't terribly hard to understand, and it compiles.

I think maybe I could do something similar with `std::declval` and `std::remove_reference` but I couldn't get that to compile.  Anyway it wouldn't be much cleaner than the above.

Does C++14 provide any non-sneaky way to get the `SpecialThing` type into `createThing` here?  Or failing that, a sneaky way that's better than my nullptr trick?

(Note:  I know I could work around this in other ways; I'm just asking to learn about the language, not to get past a serious obstacle.  Hence the silly code above that trivially wraps a standard function for no apparent reason.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a tag type:

```
#include <memory>
struct SpecialThing
{
    SpecialThing(/* some arguments */) {}
};
template<typename T>
struct Tag {
    typedef T type;
};
void f()
{
    auto createThing = [](auto typeTag, auto&&... parameters)
    {
        return std::make_unique<typename decltype(typeTag)::type>(
                        std::forward<decltype(parameters)>(parameters)...);
    };

    auto thing = createThing(Tag<SpecialThing>{} /*, some construction parameters */);
}
```

Comment: Add a `template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;` to make it a bit cleaner, and a `using T=type_t<decltype(typeTag)>;` in the body of the lambda.  Also, for `auto&&` parameters, `decltype(parameters)(parameters)` can be used to replace `std::forward<decltype(parameters)>(parameters)`.

Comment: @Yakk: Interesting point about the uselessness of `std::forward`. When *is* it needed?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  That removes the ugly nullptr trickery, and Yakk's type_t scheme seems to remove an isntance of the "typename" keyword from the lambda.  Not the pure template parameter I wanted, but pretty close to it!  I will go with this until a better answer appears (which maybe will only happen if the language changes I guess).

Comment: @Mankarse Below `x` is a variable of type `X`, where `X` can be a reference.  `T` is a non-reference type.  Then: `std::forward<X>(x)` maps `T->T&&`, `T&&->T&&` and `T&->T&`.   `decltype(x)(x)` maps `T->T`, `T&&->T&&` and `T&->T&`.  There are differences.  Plus `forward` communicates something (meaning in the name).  Within an auto-lambda, were you don't have access to the names of the types, and you are using `auto&&`, the `decltype(x)(x)` keeps things brief.  I wouldn't use it elsewhere myself, unless I wanted the `T->T` mapping.

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks for that. It's still interesting to note that in the common usage of `std::forward`, which tends to be a variation on `template<typename... T> void f(T&&... t) {g(std::forward<T>(t)...);}`, it doesn't make a difference (obviously `std::forward` has a broader applicability; buy >90% of the time it is simply applied to `T&&` parameters). Since `auto&&` parameters are essentially this, it's odd that you would prefer not using `std::forward` for `auto&&...`, but would still use it for `T&&...`. Still, it's something I hadn't considered before. (:

Comment: There's no reason to make your own tag-type. Just borrow `std::common_type<yourtypehere>`.